# Why was Wolverine's life at risk during the Weapon X procedure?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, wolverine-and-the-x-men

If Logan was shot or stabbed through the heart or brain, he wouldn't die because of his healing powers.
Professor Xavier stated that Wolverine would die if he were decapitated, so we know there are limits to his healing powers, but they seem quite extreme.

**Why did he almost die on the procedure of Weapon X, in X-men Origins?** He almost did not survive the bonding procedure.

What happened or why did he almost die?

Also, why can't Sabertooth do the same? They have the same healing powers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13032/5184), his healing powers are not limitless or necessarily immediate. The speed at which he heals has varied from one portrayal to the next.

For example, he is not absolutely immune to poisons or drugs, he is *virtually* immune. There is a small, but important difference there. That means that if Wolverine's body was damaged quickly and severely enough, his body may not have time to repair/regenerate itself. This was most likely the case with the adamantium bonding process. They needed to regulate how fast they attempted to bond the metal to his bones without overloading his regenerative powers. Go too fast and his body may not be able to keep up and end up killing him.

Sabretooth, in the movies, is Wolverine's brother. They share similar powers, but they are not necessarily identical in power or limits. Even identical, genetic human twins will not necessarily have identical immune systems. Nor will their bodies necessarily react the same way to the same stimulus. This is even more pronounced in comics where twins or siblings often have related, but drastically different powers.

Comment: 2013 Addendum, The Wolverine shows just that. Wolverine is weakened to the point where he almost dies from a few gunshots because a robot was constantly and rapidly damaging his heart, causing his healing powers to be overloaded.

Comment: You know, wolverine has numerous times regenerated from his skeleton alone..........

Comment: His healing factor abilities vary from writer to writer. There have also been times where he *hasn't* regenerated from his skeleton alone. The Sentinel blast from *Days of Future Past* immediately springs to mind.