# Would Wolverine continue to function in a vacuum?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Wolverine survive without oxygen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14362/can-wolverine-survive-without-oxygen)

The questions [How to kill Wolverine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine) and [Can Wolverine swim?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16903/can-wolverine-swim) don't seem to address what happens when Wolverine is in an oxygenless envirnonment (either underwater or in space).

If he were jettisoned into space (or abandoned on the moon), would his body die until such time as he came in contact with an nitrogen/oxygen atmosphere again? Or would it continuously die, come back to life, die, come back to life, etc, in an endless cycle?

Comment: Actually, several of the responses in "Can Wolverine Swim?" address the issue of dying and coming back to life until rescued and the potential madness in that: "Wolverine hates the water because it can kill him, again and again, until he is rescued or until the trauma of drowning, one of the most traumatic ways to die, drives him insane." - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16933/2765

Answer (score 4):

Wolverine's power is to regenerate.  Therefore any damage will be regenerated.  Wolverine's body would survive in any place that doesn't disintegrate him but his mind might not.

For example, Wolverine could suffocate in space, rendering his brain cells without any Oxygen, causing the death of those cells.  Then his body would regenerate those cells but not the memories.

Basically he would just die continuously and come back to life until he reaches a place where he can live without having to regenerate.  By that time, he would be brain dead.

Comment: What a way to go!

Answer (score 0):

1. The first problem is **oxygen**. When a cell is without oxygen it dies. However Wolverine has the ability to regenerate so he would not die because of it. Question is if his ability to regenerate is fast enough to compensate the cell decay. If it is so, I would guess that he would not even be unconscious. If not he would probably fell asleep.
2. Second issue is **pressure**. From these sources you can have an idea what can happen to a human body in space: [NASA](http://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/ask_astro/answers/970603.html) and [Geoffrey A. Landis](http://www.geoffreylandis.com/vacuum.html). Due to the skin he would certainly not blow up. However, there is a note that if your blood pressure due to some shock is to high your skin would not hold and you would blow up. So I think, if he would stay calm he is OK.

There is another problem regarding the pressure like evaporating of water in your body. It would not happen immediately but I think that even Wolverine would not be happy without water in his body. **So unless he is not able to reproduce water inside him, all cell would sooner or later die and there will be nothing from regenerate.** *But still, the point is what is the regenerating mechanism of Wolverine.*

Comment: Note: Pressure isn't much an issue - it's just one atmosphere difference. If it was, all divers would explode after diving to 10 meters. Heat dissipation isn't a problem because vacuum isolates perfectly. Your main problems are heat (sunlight) and radiation and shock which will make you lose consciousness after about 15s. More details: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=survival-in-space-unprotected-possible

Comment: The sunlight and radiation is problem for us, but not for Wolverine I supposed. The heat issue I didn't even mentioned. But I still think that sooner or later he would lose all water in his body and that would be the problem. Regarding the preassure, I was not refering to breath issue but the blood in our veins, the possibility that the blood preasure is to high that skin would not be able to hold it inside (but well I read that it could be a problem, I didn't test it)