# Which movie / cartoon / comic has Sabertooth attempting to drown Wolverine?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, wolverine, episode-identification

I think it was on Wolverine's birthday, which is usually when Sabertooth attacks him. I remember Sabertooth holding Wolverine under water in an attempt to drown him, saying something like:

> 'It won't matter if your body heals, when your brain is dead'.

I honestly can't remember if it was an animated feature or a comic...

**Does it sound familiar to anyone?**

Comment: Welcome to the site. With a bit of tidying, this makes an excellent question.

Comment: Cool, thanks @Richard

Comment: Doh - out of votes... I want to know the answer to this one...

Comment: Are you sure it was an animated feature? I'm fairly sure what you're referring to is the Ultimate X-Men comic where Sabretooth says something along the lines of *"I mean how does a healing factor fix a suffocated brain"*

Comment: ...@Richard maybe I was mistaken. I'll edit my question. And have a look for that issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an animated feature, but Sabretooth has tried drowning Logan before in Ultimate X-Men #12

[image]

Comment: ha! Brilliant!! Cheers Richard!

Comment: Darn, if only Logan were a bit more adaptable, he could just grow a set of gills and be fine.