# Has Deadpool survived being killed by burning?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

This question came to me because I read a post that said Deadpool was brought back to life after being decapitated *when his head was kept with his body* and had time to heal back together.

Does that mean that Deadpool is vulnerable to being killed **if he is burned** (either after being decapitated or just in general)?

Comment: SFF doesn't work as a forum for opinion based discussion. It operates on Q&A format. Right now voting to close this as opinion based.

Comment: I've edited it to make it less opinion-based. Deadpool must have gotten himself burned at some point...

Comment: See [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135342/62088).

Comment: Title asks "has he", body asks "can he" - two related, but *very* different questions.

Answer (score 3):

I give you [Deadpool (2nd Series) #48](http://uncannyxmen.net/comics/issue/deadpool-2nd-series-48).

[image]

Deadpool gets buried alive and is left with a lighter. Upon using the lighter he sets himself and the entire coffin on fire, after which he of course regenerates and wanders off to go and be Deadpool.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is still canon (have not heard anything to the contrary?), Thanos actually cursed Deadpool with enternal life, he is never able to die. So not even burning would be sufficient.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, think I answered this before I reread the edited question! My bad, will leave it up for a bit and see if I can track down a more accurate answer to the question asked!