# How can Wolverine sleep on a waterbed given his extra adamantium weight?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel

Can anyone explain Wolverine having no trouble sleeping in a water bed at 300 lbs+ (plus the, let’s say, 130 lbs for the woman next to him) in *X-Men: Days of Future Past*?

Comment: Is that the first scene after he goes into the past, the one that is followed by him killing someone with his bony non-adamantium claws?

Comment: Mmm, I think you're right! I might have to rewatch!

Comment: Even if he had the adamantium, at most, the bed would be awkward to sleep on. [The adamantium only adds about 105lbs](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16344/5184), giving him a total weight of roughly 300lbs. I've been on waterbeds with far more weight than that all at once. They'll slant a bit, but distributing the weight more - by doing something like laying down - will help a lot.

Comment: My research suggests that 300 pounds (plus her weight) would *probably* still be ok on a waterbed but strongly not recommended.

Comment: @Deltharis yes it is

Comment: I've slept on a waterbed for... come to think of it, most of my adult life (I suffer from a sort of early-onset arthritis; sleeping on a large hot-water bottle is soothing). From long personal experience I can tell you that Wolverine's weight is well within a waterbed's tolerances.

Comment: @phantom42 I think the real question here is how many people you've had on a waterbed with you.  We can imagine the "why" of it.

Comment: @asteri We piled probably 6 people onto it with no problem.

Comment: Haven't there been instances of his claws extending in his sleep or when awakening from a bad dream?  That's bad news for any mattress, but disaster for a waterbed.

Comment: @Simon now _that_ would be a wet dream...

Comment: since Adamantium is not real it can have any mass you like.

Comment: @Jodrell - It's real *within that piece of fiction* which is what the question was asking.

Comment: @Simon in the original *X-Men* movie, he wakes up from a nightmare and immediately pops his claws - right into Rogue.

Answer (score 31):

Because when he travels back to the 1970s, he's not *physically* travelling in time, he's being mentally projected into his former self and in 1973 he didn't have an adamantium skeleton yet.

You can see from the image below (immediately after he gets out of bed) that his claws are just bone. His weight would therefore be around 175lbs not the 300lbs he weighs in the earlier films.

This was confirmed in [an interview](http://screenrant.com/x-men-days-of-future-past-time-travel-wolverine-explained/) with the film's writer, Simon Kinsberg:

> Probably the bigger reason is that when we started thinking about **the
>   logistical realities of Kitty’s consciousness being sent back in time,
>   to her younger self, as opposed to her physical body being sent back…**
>   it was impossible.
>
> Obviously in the book it’s Kitty that’s sent back, but because we cast
>   Ellen Page in X-Men: The Last Stand, you’re talking about an actress
>   who, in the age of Michael Fassbender and James McAvoy, would have
>   been negative 20 years old. So we started thinking again. The first
>   reflex response to that was a character who doesn’t age. Wolverine is
>   the only character who would looks the same in 1973 as he does in the
>   future.”

[image]

As an aside, as has been pointed out in the comments above, most waterbed mattresses are rated to carry at least 400 pounds with no difficulty. Even if he did still have an adamantium skelton, his weight (300lbs) plus her weight (122lbs according to her bio) would present little or no chance of the mattress bursting.

Comment: Bonus joke: Q. Wolverine in 1974 is working as a greengrocer. What does he weigh? A. Oranges!

Comment: @Richard Oranges are generally priced per orange, not by weight. He must have been weighing plums or something.

Comment: @MikeScott - I have no desire to learn about Wolverine's plums.

Comment: @MikeScott Not everywhere, I'm buying oranges by weight. Though my central-europe experience might not be indicative of what Wolverine have been going through.

Comment: @Deltharis - It's the same in the UK. In the supermarkets they're priced per item but in the grocers, they're often sold by weight.

Comment: @Richard supermarkets here also sell by weight (you can even test-weigh by yourself before buying). But I think we're a bit off-topic here ;)

Answer (score 13):

**Simple answer: He doesn't have his Adamantium skeleton yet.**

This is seen in the next scene where he draws his claws to fight those mobsters and finds to his own dismay that he has plain bone claws, and not the Adamantium ones.

Furthermore, William Stryker is a youngster here. He isn't the same General Stryker who gave Wolverine his "gift".

So he couldn't have had his Adamantium. And without the Adamantium he weighs around [195lbs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16344/12551).

A typical waterbed can handle about [700kg](http://www.thewaterbedspecialist.co.uk/index.php?mod=pages&idp=9) or [1543.24](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=700%20kg%20to%20pounds&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=baiSVLXdJM6_uATymYCoAQ).

So it's safe to assume a waterbed can handle the weight of an adamantium-less Wolverine alongwith his date.

Comment: 'normal' isn't a unit-based measurement of weight (unless we have a scale starting at 'anorexic', passing through 'normal' and 'fat' to end at 'obese').

Comment: @snotwaffle - there.... :D

Comment: My inner pedant is happy now. :D